# cypress should have class assertion not working

Tags: reactjs, cypress, end-to-end

The following tests work fine

```
  it('button has "contact-next-disabled" class', () => {
    cy.get('a[rel="next"]')
  })

  it('button has "contact-next-disabled" class', () => {
    cy.get('.contact-next-disabled')
  })
```

But if I combine them with a should assertion

```
  it('button has "contact-next-disabled" class', () => {
    cy.get('a[rel="next"]').should('have.class', '.contact-next-disabled')
  })
```

Cypress gives me an assertion error

```
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<a.contact-next-disabled>' to have class '.contact-next-disabled'
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove `.` from the class name and it should work.

```
cy.get('a[rel="next"]').should('have.class', 'contact-next-disabled')
```